# XAMPP and Wordpress: Error - "Is its parent directory writable by the server?" . It is?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I just moved my live wordpress multisite to localhost. When I attempt to upload images, I get the following error:

"instagreen.png” has failed to upload. Unable to create directory D:/ProgramFiles/xampp/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2015/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

I know the issue isn't file permissions, because I used chmod 777 (I know this is a bad idea, but I had to test the issue). Here are my file permissions:
[click here to see image of file permissions, cygwin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbGLp.jpg)

I have searched online for hours, and can't find a fix.

I am using xampp and the latest version of wordpress (4.4). And I'm on windows.  Does anyone know what the solution is?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1. I went to the wp_options table in my database.
2. I executed this SQL statement: SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "upload_path"
3. I changed the upload path to wp-content/uploads.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe your `FTP` configuration. It can't create folder. I had the same problem but it was on a Ubuntu server. I just uncommented the `local_unmask` line.

Answer (score 0):

How explained in this [link](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-create-directory-error-in-wordpress-5264) it can be from different reasons. With all the details you passed in your question, I can't say which one it is. Try these [fixes](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-create-directory-error-in-wordpress-5264) one by one.